# Tool for creating relational model diagrams

Tags: database-design

I'm looking for a free and simple tool for creating relational model diagrams.

All that i need is to be able to draw tables and fields and connect fields that are foreign keys to their referenced tables.

As an example I found this [image](http://www.eng.mu.edu/corlissg/150.07F/12assets/examMid06/RG_Fig2_8_relational_model.jpg) on the net.

I don't need anything more: I want to keep schema simple and clean.

---

Thanks for your answers. However, a friend of mine suggested that I can use any vector graphics program. His advice helped me to found the beautiful "LatexDraw" editor.
It's worth a check, especially if you care about printed quality.

Comment: I don't want to make UML diagrams. I' looking for a tool that can draw the diagram i linked above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) supports**:

- Windows
- Linux
- OSX

**Performs**

- UML
- relational modeling
- and more (*lots more*)

I've used it for both UML and relational modeling with great success. I have heard the Windows version can be unstable, but *I've never experienced this personally*.

Comment: I noticed right now that DIA 0.97 has a database sheet. It's not perfect, but it seems the best tool available.

Comment: DIA is a wonderful tool. Have used it myself many times on windows. Yes it is kind of unstable sometimes, but still very useful.

Answer (score 3):

#### yUML.me

yuml.me is a really awesome text-to-diagram tool for online quick designing of UML diagrams: http://yuml.me/

#### Visio Alternatives

There are numerous free alternatives to Visio, a commercial application that does this. You can read a bit about them, and find one that suits you best at http://www.osalt.com/visio

#### Flash-based gModeler

There's also gmodeler, an online solution worked up in flash for designing UML diagrams: http://gskinner.com/gmodeler/

Comment: +1 for yUML.me it is very handy for quickie stuff

Comment: yes yUML.me is awesome ( I even created a DSL on top of its DSL http://reboltutorial.com/blog/easy-yuml-dialect-for-mere-mortals/ ) but it doesn't do Relational Model Diagrams which includes the fields.

Answer (score 2):

How about Microsoft Paint?  :)

Actually, here's one I've used for simple diagrams:  http://www.gliffy.com/
And it's collaborative, too.

Answer (score 1):

DBDesigner4 is nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server, then all you need to do is create the diagram in sql management studio, (if you expand the database item)

Answer (score 0):

And if you are using MS Access, you can always click on the relationship view tool button, and print the resulting diagram.

I've actually done this to make diagrams of simple Oracle databases by setting up table links to the Oracle tables, and by setting up the relationships in MS Access.